# An implementation of Uber's "Fare Estimator" [CodeSignal]

Tags: python-3.x, programming-challenge, lambda, community-challenge

CodeSignal put out a challenge by Uber that involves writing a "fare estimator" that involves a function dependent on cost per minute, cost per mile, ride time and ride distance.

The formula is along the lines of:

```
fare = (cost per minute) * (ride time) + (cost per mile) * (ride distance)
```

where `ride time` and `ride distance` are constant integers (or floats) and `cost per minute` and `cost per mile` are lists of integers and floats (as cost per minute and cost per mile depend on the car type).

This is my solution:

```
def fareEstimator(ride_time, ride_distance, cost_per_minute, cost_per_mile):
    y, f = [], lambda w, x, y, z: (w * x) + (y * z)
    for a, b in zip(cost_per_minute, cost_per_mile):
        y.append(f(a, ride_time, b, ride_distance))
    return y
```

I'm just looking for any kind of feedback on the code. Is there a better way to implement it? Can you recommend better coding styles? Is my algorithm good or is it a steaming pile of wank? Leave any feedback you want!

You can check out the full challenge here (but you might need to sign up): https://app.codesignal.com/company-challenges/uber/HNQwGHfKAoYsz9KX6

Comment: Can you show how you expect the function to be called?  In particular, it helps to know what types the arguments will be.

Comment: It's just called by an external code judge (I didn't implement a main function).

Comment: Ah, sorry, I see you have described the types of the arguments in the paragraph above the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are a few tips:

- Unless it makes the code easier to read, avoid multiple assignments in one line. making your code shorter does not necessarily make it better, faster nor more maintainable.
- Give better names to your variables
- Use [type hints](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html)

So, your code could be changed to this:

```py
from typing import Iterable

def fareEstimator(ride_time: float, ride_distance: float, cost_per_minute_list: Iterable[float],
                  cost_per_mile_list: Iterable[float]) -> Iterable[float]:
    result = []

    def calculateFare(ride_time: float, ride_distance: float, cost_per_minute: float,
                      cost_per_mile: float) -> float:
        return ride_time*cost_per_minute + ride_distance*cost_per_mile

    for cost_per_minute, cost_per_mile in zip(cost_per_minute_list, cost_per_mile_list):
        result.append(calculateFare(ride_time, ride_distance, cost_per_minute, cost_per_mile))

    return result
```